# What is the purpose of including "all" in @media rules?

Tags: css

So you see a lot of code examples do something like

```
@media all and (max-width:640px) {
    div {
        background-color:red;
    }
}
```

Now afaik, the keywords "all" and "screen" and some others are for selecting the device type this applies to and the line is just supposed to provide a boolean output.

Since "all" applies to every device, one would imagine that its always 1 and (1 && x) always equals x so "all and" should make no difference whatsoever.

I tried out

```
@media (max-width:640px) {
    div {
        background-color:red;
    }
}
```

and at least my browsers agree. Is there anything else I should know about?

Comment: Quick reading of the documentation tells me that all is for media type, which is separate from screen width.

Answer (score 1):

See the spec: https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/

> The ‘print’ and ‘screen’ media types are defined in HTML4. The complete list of media types in HTML4 is: ‘aural’, ‘braille’, ‘handheld’, ‘print’, ‘projection’, ‘screen’, ‘tty’, ‘tv’. CSS2 defines the same list, deprecates ‘aural’ and adds ‘embossed’ and ‘speech’. Also, **‘all’ is used to indicate that the style sheet applies to all media types**.
>
> ...
>
> A shorthand syntax is offered for media queries that apply to all media types; the keyword ‘all’ can be left out (along with the trailing ‘and’). I.e. **if the media type is not explicitly given it is ‘all’.**

```
/* I.e. these are identical: */

@media all and (min-width:500px) { … }
@media (min-width:500px) { … }

/* As are these: */

@media (orientation: portrait) { … }
@media all and (orientation: portrait) { … }
```

---

In addition, the following media types: 'tty', 'tv', 'projection', 'handheld', 'braille', 'embossed', 'aural' have been deprecated in [Media Queries Level 4](https://www.w3.org/TR/mediaqueries-4/#media-types).

Answer (score 0):

**all** refers to: all media type devices, **print**: used for printing, **screen**: used for desktop screens, mobiles, tablets etc and **speech**: used for screen-readers that "reads" the page out loud.

In your case where you have specified media type as `all`, you can try printing the page by right clicking. The printed page will have all the styles applied in short it will exactly look the same.

Now take another example where you specify the media type as `screen`. If you try to print the page you will not see all the styles getting applied to the page as the styles were defined for screen alone.

If one does not specify `all` in media query it is by default taken as `all`.

```css
@media screen {
  div {
    color: blue;
  }
  .print{
    display: none;
  }
}

@media print and (min-width: 200px){
  div{
    color: tomato;
  }
  div.not('.example'){
    display:none !important;
  }
  .print{
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="example">
  <div>Try printing me. See if this blue color appears while printing</div>
  <div class="print">I am only visible while printing.</div>
</div>
```